# htop status bars in motd

Tags: linux, bash, htop

I'd like to put the `htop` status bars, that show the percentage of CPU usage and memory, in my MOTD, so that every time I log in I see an overview about the systems health status.

Any idea how to achieve this?

UPDATE: Especially the visualization with percentage bars is what I want. Not only the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it my way. (sorry for so much bash code)

```
#
# cpu usage
#
cpu_cores=$(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "processor" | wc -l)
i=0
cpu_out_1=($(cat /proc/stat | grep "cpu"))
# the longer we sleep the more accurate is the calculated percentage
sleep 0.3
cpu_out_2=($(cat /proc/stat | grep "cpu"))

cpu_out_colcount=($(cat /proc/stat | head -n 1))
cpu_out_colcount=${#cpu_out_colcount[@]}

while [ $i -lt $cpu_cores ]; do
    cpu_index=$(($i * $cpu_out_colcount + $cpu_out_colcount + 1))
    cpu_load_1=(${cpu_out_1[@]:$cpu_index:4})
    cpu_load_2=(${cpu_out_2[@]:$cpu_index:4})
    cpu_sum_1=$((cpu_load_1[0] + cpu_load_1[1] + cpu_load_1[2] + cpu_load_1[3]))
    cpu_sum_2=$((cpu_load_2[0] + cpu_load_2[1] + cpu_load_2[2] + cpu_load_2[3]))
    cpu_sum_diff=$((cpu_sum_2 - cpu_sum_1))
    cpu_idle_1=${cpu_load_1[3]}
    cpu_idle_2=${cpu_load_2[3]}
    cpu_idle_diff=$((cpu_idle_2 - cpu_idle_1))
    cpu_perc=$((100 - (100 * $cpu_idle_diff / $cpu_sum_diff)))
    printf "${COLOR_HEADER}"
    printf '  CPU %-2d ' "$i"
    printf "${COLOR_NONE}"
    print_bar $cpu_perc 30 60
    printf "\n"
    i=$((i+1));
done;
```

And `print_bar` is a function, that generates a colored percentage bar:

```
function print_bar() {
    prcntg=$1
    warn=$2
    crit=$3
    bar_color=$COLOR_OK
    if [ $prcntg -gt $warn ]; then
        bar_color=$COLOR_WARN
    fi
    if [ $prcntg -gt $crit ]; then
        bar_color=$COLOR_CRIT
    fi

    bar_width_fill=$((BAR_WIDTH * prcntg / 100))
    bar_width_empty=$((BAR_WIDTH - bar_width_fill))

    printf -v bar "%${bar_width_fill}s" ""
    printf -v nbar "%${bar_width_empty}s" ""
    printf "${bar_color}"
    printf '%3d%% %s' "$prcntg" "${bar// /█}"
    printf "${COLOR_NONE}"
    printf '%s' "${nbar// /▒}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534591/htop-output-to-human-readable-file

especially the answer from the author of htop - Hisham H M

short answer: you can't really do it, use `ps` instead